# Как удалить записи использовав Ajax запросы

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

у меня есть скрипт который выводит данные в таблицу (в моём случае это книги в библиотеке)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/Book/JsonBook",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            Id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                            Name: { validation: { required: true } },
                            Author: { validation: { required: true } },
                            YearOfPublishing: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1 } },

                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                pageable: true,
                height: 550,
                columns: [
                    { field: "Name", title: "Name", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                    { field: "Author", title: "Author", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                    { field: "YearOfPublishing", title: "Year of publishing", width: "120px" },
                    { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }],
                editable: "inline"
            });
        });

        function customBoolEditor(container, options) {
            var guid = kendo.guid();
            $('<input class="k-checkbox" id="' + guid + '" type="checkbox" name="Discontinued" data-type="boolean" data-bind="checked:Discontinued">').appendTo(container);
            $('<label class="k-checkbox-label" for="' + guid + '">​</label>').appendTo(container);
        }
    </script>
```

Стал вопрос для удаления данных через Ajax запросы, но как это сделать я не совсем понимаю (очень слаб в js) и если кто-то хотя бы натолкнет меня в правильное русло как мне это сделать ,буду благодарен

P.S. дополнительный вопрос не по теме ,у меня есть кнопка которая переводит страницу добавления новой книги

```
<button class="k-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AddBook")'" id="get">Add</button>
```

как ее перенести в скрипт ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял вам нужен пример js скрипта в котором реализуется отправка запросов

Кнопка на html

```
<button onclick="delete_book('123')">Delete Book</button>
```

JS скрипт который отправит соответствующий запрос вашему PHP скрипту:

```
function delete_book(book_id) {
    $.post('/api/del_book.php', {
        'id_book':book_id
    }, function (data) { //обработка принятых данных
        if(data=='ok') { //если пришел ответ с текстом "ok"
            alert('Книга удалена'); //выводим сообщение
        }
    });
}
```

А в скрипт поместить необходимо эту строчку (если не ошибаюсь)

```
location.href='@Url.Action("AddBook")';
location.href=Url.Action("AddBook"); //возможно так
```

Comment: location.href='@Url.Action("AddBook")'; оно сразу перебрасывает на страницу добавления ,а не создает кнопку

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста подробнее что именно вам необходимо реализовать?

Comment: для начала я хотел бы добавить кнопку в скрипт ,которая будет перенаправлять меня на нужную мне страницу ,сейчас эта кнопка находится не в скрипте (зачем ? хочу чтоб кнопка была в самой таблице ,а не под ней )

Comment: Дело в том что формирование таблицы в виде html-кода у вас происходит немного в других местах, внутри функции kendoGrid, а не видя ее - не могу вам помочь